# How to specify numba jitclass when the class' attribute contains an instance of self

Tags: python, class, jit, numba

I have a simple Python class:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._left = self
        self._right = self

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self._left

    @left.setter
    def left(self, value):
        self._left = value

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self._right

    @right.setter
    def right(self, value):
        self._right = value
```

I would like to jit this class but it isn't clear how to define the types when `self._left` and `self._right` are of `Node` object type. I came across this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667906/how-to-specify-numba-jitclass-when-the-classs-attribute-contains-another-class) answer that uses `.class_type.instance_type` but that example only refers to a class attribute that contains a *different* class instance. In my case, since `Node` is not defined yet, I cannot declare the following spec:

```
spec=[("_left", Node.class_type.instance_type),
      ("_right", Node.class_type.instance_type),
     ]

@jitclass(spec)
class Node(object):
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this [example](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/fdbe264706881d19e97494e5ca794c540479a4d0/examples/linkedlist.py) - numba has a `deferred_type` function for this case.

```
node_type = numba.deferred_type()
spec=[
    ("_left", node_type),
    ("_right", node_type),
]

@jitclass(spec)
class Node:
    # omitted

# define the deferred type
node_type.define(Node.class_type.instance_type)

# class can be used!
a = Node()
b = Node()
a.left = b
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if it's possible if we can subclass (or inherit) from the `Node` class? I'm getting an error saying that I can't subclass a jitclass